# Swift 3 - UITextView won't update

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a problem with the following code:

```
@IBOutlet var infoBox: UITextView!

LibPerso.startGPSLocationService(completion: {(response:Response, location:CLLocation?) -> Void in
    if(response.hasError()){
        //...
    }
    if let currentLocation = location, location != nil, location?.coordinate.latitude != 0, location?.coordinate.longitude != 0{
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(self.infoBox.text) //#1
            self.infoBox.text = "Lat : \(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude) \r\nLng: \(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)"
            print(self.infoBox.text) //#2
        }
    }
})
```

When I open this view and call the method `startGPSLocationService` (method in my library; it's a service to get the GPS location), each time I have a return, I successfully update the textView.
The problem is that when I change the view (go back to the previous view) and reopen this view, all the code is called, but the `infoBox` is not updated on the screen.

I have two print statements that print the following:

> #1: Lat : 48.7922072828896  Lng: 10.16013687006524
>   #2: Lat : 48.7922120134739  Lng: 10.16015784907253

So the inbox field is correctly updated, but on my screen, nothing happens.

I already tried to do `self.infoBox.setNeedsLayout()` or `setNeedsDisplay()`, but that doesn't change anything either.

I think that the reference to `infoBox` gets lost in traffic when I go back and reopen this view.

Comment: is completion block called when you come back from another screen. Completion block NOT the method. ?

Comment: Yes, the two "print" is displayed, so the completion block is called

Comment: check frame of  infoBox .

Comment: When you come back from another view can you try setting some hardcode value ? It is possible that your latitude and longitude didn't actually change.

Comment: Already check, i have displayed the current value of the infobox in the first "print" and the second (value returned by the completion) in the second "print".

Comment: The problem is likely how you *"go back and reopen this view"* ... show us the code - or at least describe - how you are doing that.

Comment: Does initially textview display text

Comment: Yes, it display "no info" and in the viewDidLoad, i display the last information stored in a field (this part work)

Comment: can you add the code which describes what you are doing when  "go back and reopen this view" as suggested by @DonMag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very likely related to this part of your description:

> when i change the view (go back to the previous view) and reopen this view

It sounds like you have, for example, ViewControllerOne (`VC1`) and ViewControllerTwo (`VC2`). Your `infoBox` is in `VC2`.

You navigate from `VC1` to `VC2` - probably with a modal or push segue - and you set the text of `infoBox`.

Then you navigate back to `VC1`, and at some point *"reopen"* `VC2`... at which point you are surprised that `infoBox` no longer contains the previously set text.

Does that fairly accurately describes the situation? If so, the there is the problem. When you *"reopen this view"*, you are creating a ***new*** instance of `VC2` - which does not, of course, contain the text you had set in `infoBox`. You are not simply *re-displaying* the old one.

What you'll need to do is either pass the text back from `VC2` to `VC1`, or create some sort of data-class to store your new text (or, probably better, to store the new Lat / Lon values).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Good explanation. And i understand why it doesn't work... My completion block stay in the previous instance and use the inbox of my previous instance too....